# Convert a Hexadecimal to Binary values

Tags: flutter, dart

How to convert a Hexadecimal to Binary values.

Here is my code:

```
String authSign() {
    if (CheckDate % 2 == 0) {
      return Signature = H + B + Sk;
    } else {
      return Signature = B + H + Sk;
    }
  }

  ;

  var key = utf8.encode(authSign());
  var stringSha = sha256.convert(key);
  var stringHex = hex.decode(stringSha.toString());
  var finalHex  = hex.encode(stringHex.toList());
```

and here is the result:

```
flutter: dad85aac19b632a71b4759078bf90cbe4fba354582454f0445bc3bb8e3e4c587
```

and the result I want is:

```
64616438356161633139623633326137316234373539303738626639306362653466626133353435383234353466303434356263336262386533653463353837
```

Comment: is there any features on flutter simillar with bin2hex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `BigInt.parse` or `BigInt.tryParse` and set its `radix` parameter to `16`:

```dart
String hex = "dad85aac19b632a71b4759078bf90cbe4fba354582454f0445bc3bb8e3e4c587";
BigInt bin = BigInt.parse(hex,radix: 16);
```

Comment: Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Positive input exceeds the limit of integer this appears, or null appears

Comment: Then use a `BigInt` variable instead of `int`.

Comment: do flutter have a feature same as bin2hex?

Comment: I don't think so